# Count E-Mails from 2 tables

Tags: sql, teradata

Finding it challenging to solve this

Table 1 has usersids (around 2 Million)

Table 2 has all user ids with email addresses (around 150 Million)

Table 3 has email addresses (around 100  users who are subscribed to a certain email program)

Need to count users from table 1 who are subscribed vs. not subscribed to the email program.

I tried

```
select b.email_address
from
table_1 a
left outer join table_2 b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
intersect
select email from table_3
```

but this is an incorrect way. I need to get exact count of subscribers to email program. Any help appreciated.

Comment: BTW, this presumably has to do with MySQL or Teradata, not both... probably best to clarify which tag applies

Answer (score 1):

I guess the challenge here is that the second table (the big one) has multiple users per email address.  Because there are so few email addresses, I would be inclined to approach this as:

```
with emailusers as (
      select distinct userid
      from table2 t2 join
           table3 t3
           on t2.email = t3.email
     )
select sum(case when eu.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as subscribed,
       sum(case when eu.userid is null then 1 else 0 end) as notsubscribed
from table1 t1 left join
     emailusers eu
     on t1.userid = eu.userid;
```

Comment: getting an error saying string contains an untranslatable character

Comment: "the second table (the big one) has multiple users per email address."  -- I suspect that is the case too. I would not be surprised if a similar condition is present as well - Users with multiple email addresses.

Comment: @GauravMehta . . . My answer has no explicit strings in it.  I have no idea what that error message might be referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You want a join and a CASE WHEN that describes whether a record was found or not.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.email is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_subscribed, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.email IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subscribed
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS c
    ON b.email = c.email
```

Now this makes some assumptions about your data, most especially that there are not duplicate email addresses in table_3. You should be able to verify that not_subscribed + subscribed equals SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT usersids) FROM table_1. If it does not, you should do these joins one at a time and determine where records are being lost/added.

Comment: I dont think it is working. Its showing 1M records as subscribed and 0 as unsubscribed. However the table 1 has 2 Million records.

Comment: I think you need to do some analysis of your tables. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1;` `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_1 GROUP BY 1 HAVING cnt > 1;` `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2;` `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_2 GROUP BY 1 HAVING cnt > 1;` `SELECT COUNT(a.user_id) cnt_A, COUNT(b.user_id) cnt_B FROM table_A AS a LEFT JOIN table_b ON a.user_id = b.user_id;` `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_3;` `SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_3 GROUP BY 1 HAVING cnt > 1;` etc  would be good places to start. Basically, dig into your tables.